# Округления числа до двух знаков

Tags: java

Как округлить число до двух знаков после запятой?

```
double result=Math.round(((a*b)*100.0)/100);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2808648/3129992

Answer (score 0):

я знаю 2 способа, `format` и `printf`

```
public class TestTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double a = 0.123456789;

        System.out.format("округлить до 2х знаков - %.2f", a);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("округлить до 2х знаков - %.2f", a);//аналог
    }
}
```

и вот тебе более подробная статейка на эту тему
https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1412-formatiruem-vihvod-chisel-v-java

Answer (score -1):

Вот так не пробовал?
`result1 = result.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);`
Цифра в скобках указывает в java округление до 2 знаков double типа.

Comment: Пробовал ругается на метод Cannot resolve method 'setScale(int, RoundingMode)'

Comment: Это не ответ, а короткая догадка. Это в комментарий надо помещать.

Comment: @d6xdmxnneee, это будет работать только для [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), для обычных double или Double - нет.